# python win32api keyboard event shift + home do not select text

Tags: python, windows-10, keyboard-events

I need to select text in the game so that I can then copy it to the clipboard, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work, and so i use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd>.

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_HOME, 0, 0)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_HOME, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
```

I also use VK_RSHIFT, VK_LSHIFT. This code doesn't select text even in the text editor.
When i press buttons the text is selected.
There is only one condition: use win32api library or similar to it in execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it, but it works

```
import win32api

win32api.keybd_event(16, 42, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(36, 71, 1)
win32api.keybd_event(36, 71, 3)
win32api.keybd_event(16, 42, 2)
```

I found this by researching keyboard libraries